# My love broke the chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

My [love for a movie](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/5286132/history) was *way* too much for the chat to handle and it apparently broke for some users running Internet Explorer.

The obvious issue is that it they are using Internet Explorer, but I thought It would be worthwhile to know regardless.

Comment: Hmm... when I first read the title of the post I thought, "It's kinda early in the week for Friday..."

Comment: More pressing, what was the movie. ;-)

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this will be a "don't do that."

Comment: [It's always Friday in Iceland](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21413/170049) And the movie was Dark Knight Rises :D

Comment: It's the price you pay for being an evil nazi mod, even chat turned against you... Next time better think twice before closing my totally legit, interesting and useful question. ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos You're just jealous of my uber-awesome EXPS

Comment: @TylerShads Actually I'm jealous that the question got down votes, for some reason the ProgSE crowd keeps up voting trivia crap...

Comment: @YannisRizos Just do what I do, close with extreme prejudice and yell at them.

Answer (score 14):

I have no idea why that breaks IE, so I'll happily pass that blame on to Redmond. But you shouldn't have been able to post that message in the first place (we [missed a bit of validation](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1017669#1017669)).
As you have [learned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5288290#5288290) in the meantime, that's already fixed.

Comment: It was completely by accident too, of course ;D